# How to create a function to redirect a specified page to another page

Tags: functions, redirect

Issue: I have a custom theme and can, of course, code pages for categories (assigned by creating a page with the name and assigning it the custom page -- eg, Create page "pine trees" and assign it pine-trees.php).

However, WordPress does a thing where it includes a string to a page (eg domain.com/category/pine-trees/ ) which means I cannot create a page to assign. (I realize this is a permalinks option where I chose category string, but this is better for indexing, organization, and SEO, plus all my links are built on it).

Now, you can't just create a page called "Category/Pine-Trees" because WordPress won't let you use slashes in the title, so that's where I'm stuck.

I'd like to be able to make custom pages for any category/ subcategory on my site.

Can I solve this by redirecting? Is there a code I could enter into functions.php to tell it to redirect "domain.com/category/pine-trees" to "domain.com/pine-trees"?

Thanks for any help,

JM

Comment: This plugin does what I think you are looking for. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Hi KnightHawk, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, it seems like that plugin might be capable of the tasks, but looking at the support tab, people are afraid to update the plugin because of a bunch of errors reported. Doesn't seem very safe for a site. I'd like to approach this with code if anyone has any suggestions.